Loading drawables different contexts
Is there a difference in loading drawables programatically using applicationContext vs Activity Context

Yes, in some cases there is a difference.
Application and Activity can have different themes (specified in the AndroidManifest.xml).
Certain types of drawable resources (e.g. shape drawables) can reference attributes that depend on the theme (e.g. colors).
This can cause the same drawable to look differently when created using application and activity contexts.
